# Java application works on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: java, database, windows, macos

I am looking for any idea that might help me solve the issue I currently have. I have inherited a JAVA application that reads an Excel file, creates a text file containing SQL code and connects to a Sybase DB to update it. It uses SweetDEV as db connector and it works perfectly on Mac.

Problem is that it is unable to connect to the DB on Windows, reporting that the username and password provided are incorrect. Which is not true since they are the same it uses on Mac and it works. I have tried using another application to connect to the Sybase DB using this pair and it worked.

I connect to the server using its IP not an alias - I have also tried with the alias but it didn't work.

I have googled and I came up upon a thread that suggested the problem could be connected to the encoding used and as solution it was proposed to add this to the connection string: "?charset=iso_1". Which was already in place from the beginning. So it is not an encoding problem.

I have created a simple class that connects to the DB and retrieves the server's metadata using another driver (com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver) and it works. I really don't want to redo the whole application and I am puzzled why it works on one OS and not the other.

If anyone has any idea of what might be causing this, please share. I am completely baffled by all this and I have ran out of ideas.

Thanks in advance,

João

PS: Here's the error it returns - again I know it is not a username / pw issue because I am able to connect using them.

```
[10/4/2011 16:29:37] com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.ServiceManager INFO The service [CONFIGXML_SERVICE] with class name [com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.configxml.ConfigXmlService] was successfully registered.
[10/4/2011 16:29:37] com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.ServiceManager INFO The service [QUERYCALLER_SERVICE] with class name [com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datacaller.querycaller.QueryCallerService] was successfully registered.
[10/4/2011 16:29:37] com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datasource.DataSourceService ERROR An error append while initializing the DataSource.com.ideo.sweetdev.core.exception.TechnicalException: An error append while initializing the DataSource.
at com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datasource.DataSourceService.initDataSource(DataSourceService.java:437)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datasource.DataSourceService.retrievePool(DataSourceService.java:218)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datasource.DataSourceService.configure(DataSourceService.java:174)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.ServiceManager.instantiateService(ServiceManager.java:424)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.ServiceManager.getServiceByName(ServiceManager.java:508)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:285)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datasource.DataSourceHelper.getDBService(DataSourceHelper.java:41)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datacaller.querycaller.QueryCallerService.getQueryCaller(QueryCallerService.java:108)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datacaller.querycaller.QueryCallerService.getQueryCaller(QueryCallerService.java:133)
at com.ideo.sweetdev.data.service.datacaller.querycaller.QueryCallerHelper.getQueryCaller(QueryCallerHelper.java:59)
at connexionSQL.ExecutionFichierRequetes.<init>(ExecutionFichierRequetes.java:41)
at interfaces.ChoixEnvironnements$3.run(ChoixEnvironnements.java:149)
java.sql.SQLException: JZ00L: Echec de la connexion. Examinez les SQLWarnings associ?es ? cette exception pour la ou les raisons suivantes :
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(Unknown Source)

...
```

Comment: perhaps the faulty OS doesnt have the libraries you expect it to have ?

Comment: ManseUK, I have the source and all the libraries used by the application. I even ran the application using the PC of a colleague that develops in JAVA and it didn't work either.Maybe I didn't understand what you meant, could you elaborate?

Comment: Is it possible, that the database does not accept the user/password combination from the Windows host? Maybe the server does not only check user and password, but user, password and client-host.

Comment: Hi Ulf, thanks for your comment. I have used SQLAdvantage in Windows to connect to the DB and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Do you have access to the database logs?  They might provide more information.  One guess: Windows might be assuming that the remote database is running SQL Server and either (a) authenticating against Windows instead of passing the username/password directly to the database or (b) "fixing" the username by adding the Windows domain to it.

Comment: Hi Harry, that's going to be my next move: talk to the DBA's to see if they can provide me the log. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it possibly be a classpath issue? On Linux / MacOS, classpaths are defined slightly differently e.g.

```
java -cp jar1.jar:jar2.jar:
```

On Windows the colon becomes a semi-colon.

```
java -cp jar1.jar;jar2.jar;
```

Is that possibly the issue?

Alternatively, can you eavesdrop on the connection via a tool e.g. wireshark? Just to compare what your java app sends in one case and in the other?

Also can you run in MacOS (the good OS) and point to the db in Windows?

Comment: Hi djob, thanks for your input. I doubt that it is a classpath issue but I will recheck. Unfortunately I can not use something like wireshark :( The database is not located in Windows or Mac but on a server that runs some *nix OS.

Comment: You can still run wireshark locally to compare what's being sent. Or use a proxy like tcpmon or charles web proxy

Comment: Hi djob, I'll see if I can use any of those and will keep you posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a test by setting a user and password consisting of plain ASCII? So an encoding problem is indeed excluded. (Unfortunately encoding happens on several layers.)

Sorry, you already excluded that.

Wrong database/scheme name? Not likely.

Using verbose option for the SybDriver?

Comment: Hi Joop, yep it is not an encoding problem nor a wrong database/scheme name. I can connect using exactly the same parameters on Mac and in Windows if I use SQLAdvantage. Thx anyway.